# Change default position of "camera shared" marker on Firefox

Tags: firefox, webcam, privileges

On Firefox, a marker appears at the center in the top border of my screen whenever an app is allowed access to the camera.
Are there any config options of Firefox which would allow me to set the default position to the top right corner? Maybe even to avoid it from appearing, since the hardware led from the camera already lets me know the camera is on.

Comment: Likely with userChrome.css.or *about:config*. Two answers are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852775/how-to-hide-firefox-camera-icon-overlay-in-windows . To also remove the *microphone* indicator, see https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/78pjz1/how_do_i_remove_this_microphone_indicator/ .

Comment: first link allowed to hide it, thanks